# Checking two variables on condition from localStorage:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage, jsonparser

Is there a way to check to variable in localstorage ?

```
Storage {user: 'undefined', new: '{"_id":"61dd228336a3923d2286b994","email":"ahmadsa…","updatedAt":"2022-01-11T06:24:03.675Z","__v":0}', lscache-localhost:preview:v20180702-cacheexpiration: '27376332', lscache-localhost:preview:v20180702: '{}', length: 4}
```

And sometimes the data may be on the user property base on user login . below is the login that returns the property in user

```
   Storage {user: '{"team_members":{"memberFullname1":"memberFullname…","updatedAt":"2022-01-10T01:43:30.288Z","__v":0}', new: 'null', length: 2}
```

How can I create condition that checks both property an only return the ones that contain a value ?

Base on user log in, I can only use one variable either new or user. Is there not away I can check two conditions before rendering my data from localStorage ?

This is the Method I try. But it only check the first condition even though the second condition is there, it return. Uncaught error in Json.parse()

```
if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
  if (localStorage.getItem("new")) {
    setUser(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("new")));
  } else if (localStorage.getItem("user")) {
    setUser(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("user")));
  }
  return;
}
```

Is there a way I can check both condition ? Your time is really appreciated. please  I am a brother need..
And lastly how can I prevent re-rendering of the state

Comment: Is your Json correctly formatted? Since you are getting an error on the first `JSON.parse()`

Comment: Yes it's. the problem is coming from the localstorage.getItem("new") if the new user exist (data) coming from server and I called JSON.parse(localstorage.get("new") then  my data is retrieve successfully. but there are times that the data may not be on "new" it will be on the "user". base on there login... And that's why I want to check before rendering.

Answer (score 0):

If `user` undefined, do `new`, if that's undefined, do `{}`, parse.

```
if (typeof Storage !== "undefined") {
  setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.user || localStorage.new || '{}'));
}
```

Though, if you look at `new`, it's not the same as `user`, in terms of structure so you might want to fix that else they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found these code allows me to check both conditions and it didn't return error like the previous one.

```
   useEffect(() => {
    const fetchStates = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        "https://nigerian-states-info.herokuapp.com/api/v1/states"
      );
      setStates(result.data.data);
    };
    fetchStates();
    if (localStorage.user === "undefined") {
      return setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("new")));
    } else if (localStorage.new === "undefined") {
      return setUser(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")));
    }
  }, [formData, user]);
```

Finally after a bunch of try and error, I finally arrived at that part. I want to sent my sincere appreciation to all those who took there time and review my issues even those that did not get to answer. I send A BIG THANK YOU especially to lawrence cherone your idea was a great helpful in shaping my thought. thank you all

Comment: Why you need `formData` as dependency? Seems incorrect.